# Tinymce simulating keypress after editor.insertcontent('@');?

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I have tinymce and I wish to simulate a keydown or keyup event after using editor.insertcontent.

Basically a custom button on the toolbar inserts "@" in the editor and if I were to type it in, it'd initiate a plugin (suggester) but since pressing the button inserts the symbol directly instead of having keyup or keydown (guessing here) the suggester plugin does not initialize. Is there maybe a way to simulate the "@" keyup or keydown event after the editor.insertcontent('@'); so it triggers?

Or any other way to insert @ from a button to the editor textarea without the editor.insertcontent way, while maintaining keyup or keydown or both?

Much appreciated guys

Comment: contact the plugin developer and ask them for a fix?

Comment: Already tried :) He said eventually if he has time he will develop it but that might not be in the forseeable future... :/

Comment: could you post the link to the github for the code of this custom button?

Comment: It might be easier to use this i prepped it.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78706473/tinykereso.zip

The ajax query is not important, if the delimiter gets properly in the textarea, the mention plugin will initialize and show so it does not matter if there are no results.

Comment: copy/paste to insert the @ will also be an issue. will look at this when I have time as this is customization to a plugin you need to (probably) generate an income from for the client you're doing it for.

Comment: I can't find a plugin called "suggester" in the tinymce setup. can you point it out please?

Comment: The suggester should not be something that is used in my example, the github page uses it for " : " but not for else. I am not sure how did you get to see that in my prepped example. :) Much appreciated by the way.

Comment: I was trying to find out which plugin it was that you were talking about with the "@" and has it pop up. It's called "mention" not "suggester"

Comment: The mention plugin is in the tinymce plugin dir. I have referred to it as "mention" several times before so I was confused what suggester you wished to have :)

Comment: sorry I was looking at "the suggester plugin does not initialize", didn't see the 1 time you mentioned it in the comments :P